# Is there a separator character or code for QR code content?

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

I'm developing an app which uses QR codes for certain app-specific data.  I would like to make it possible for a person who is not yet a user of the app to scan the code, which would take them to our app url where they would get info about our app and a link to download.  If a user has our app and they scan the code, our app extracts the info it recognizes and does its thing.  I have tried to encode a string like:
info="url:http://myapp.mobi"+"\nmyappdata:data..."
but the QR scanners I've tried out don't see the newline as a separator and try to send the entire string as a URL.  When I scanned this QR code with Android, it created a note containing the content of the QR code.  Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: A QR code contains some text or some data. It doesn't perform actions. It is up to a QR code scanner to interpret the scanned text/data. Only your app would understand what to do with your "info=....\nmyappdata..." text in the QR code. So in short, no, what you want can't be done if the code is to be scanned by any generic scanner.

Comment: It seems to me that the solution is to encode your data into the URL.  When this URL is scanned by a generic scanner, it is used to open your website (which can ignore the extra data in the query string).  When it is scanned by your app, it knows how to parse the query string in order to get the data it needs.

Comment: Brilliant!  Very creative way to solve this problem.  Thank you!

Comment: This sounds very similar to something I am doing on iOS. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I took the approach that @Paulw11 suggests, which worked great, and works with any QR scanner.